# Spring MVC passing model as dto to form?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have question about passing my entity models to controllers and after that to form on view, where user can populate necessary data.

So right now it is like that :

Controller

```
User user = new UserModel();
model.add("user", user);
```

View

```
Form thing to populate values
```

And the question is: 
I want to not pass entity itself but DTO for safety purposes.
Because DTO must be Immutable without setters, How then I will set those mandatory fields on view ? 
I need to make something like POJO to just passing data? Then After population of data, convert POJO to entity with assembler and save it in my database?
Or there are other ways to do that ?

Edit. I use Thymeleaf on view side.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with an example DTO and what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think so it would be DTO because DTOs are immutable but ok. Example ObjectDTO need to have 6 fields : 2 enums, 1 long, 1 float, 2 Strings. I want on View side that User should populate this data for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Form object, which is a simple pojo with setters and getters to capture your Form data. To enforce validation rules such as `@NotNull` have a look at `javax.validation.constraints`. You should have a `@Service` component that has to be `@Autowired` in your `@Controller`to populate form data into one or more `@Entity`and call a `@Repository` component, that has to be `@Autowired` in your `@Service`, for database operations.

Comment: I know spring thing just asking about design. So you are suggesting me to use POJO with setters and getter for that purpose ?

Comment: Yes, use a POJO to capture data in your `@Controller` component, and only use `@Entity` in your `@Repository` component.